# MKMapView causes Lag when scrolling while it is rendering/loading map

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I have a ScrollView that contains an MKMapView in it, I noticed a lag while scrolling while the mapView is still loading/rendering. But the lag is gone once its fully loaded.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Thank you

Heres how I add it

```
var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude.doubleValue, longitude: longitude.doubleValue);
var span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1);   

var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span);

var mapView:MKMapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 140));
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false);
scrollView.addSubview(mapView);
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem :(

Comment: I've done mapview's before with 100's of annotations and not had much of an issue. You do need to load a load of image tiles though as you pan/scroll so you'll need a decent network connection.